# MongoShell query to MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.getCollection('parentCollection').find({"mapObject.someField" : {$exists: true}})
```

i want this to convert into method like below
.

```
@Query("{mapObject.someField :{$exists : true}}")
List<Parent> findByMapKey(String id);
```

Here i am getting null pointer exception while running application

```
@Query("{mapObject.someField :{$exists : true}}")
here someField needs to be dynamic not fixed so i want my id to be passed in place of someField
```

Same question exists here as well
[How to get parent object based upon key from child map in MongoRepository JAVA SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824067/how-to-get-parent-object-based-upon-key-from-child-map-in-mongorepository-java-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above by **@Valijon** it is not possible with **@Query** annotation. Still if anyone finds a way please share. Following is how i achieved it using **MongoTemplate**

```
package com.somepackage.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
import com.yourpackagestructure.Parent;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

@Service
public class Service{

   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   public Service(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
   }

   public List<Parent> getParentList(String mapKey){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("someMap." + mapKey).exists(true));
    List<Parent> parents = mongoTemplate.find(query,Parent.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with **MongoRepository**. Instead, use [MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843120/how-to-write-mongotemplate-query-and-criteria-for-a-complex-document-structure).

Comment: Do you have any link to the similar example.

Comment: I've posted an example, click MongoTemplate link